# Using the same class across multiple functions

Tags: plugin-development

I'm creating a plugin which will add "-" and "+" increment buttons around quantity input field. I left some essential lines to more clearly present the problem.

I created class `qty_increment_buttons_settings` with 2 settings in admin, numeric value and checkbox, using settings API. This numeric value is passed as a variable to js file. I wrote similar plugin before and it worked, but here it's more complex - I would like to use this new instance of class in my other functions, for example within `qib_create_button` to access checkbox value, through public function `qib_get_settings` defined within this class.

Also, is there any way I could specify `true` and `false` within `add_action` hooks, so I don't need to create 2 extra functions?

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'run_qib' );
function run_qib() {
    if (! is_cart() && ! is_product()) return; // Only if it's product or cart page.
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'qty_increment_buttons' );
}

function qty_increment_buttons( ) {     

    $plugin_slug = 'qty-increment-buttons-for-woocommerce';
    $plugin_short_slug = 'qty-increment-buttons';

    add_action('wp_head', 'qib_apply_styles', 20);  
    wp_enqueue_script( $plugin_short_slug, plugins_url() . '/' . $plugin_slug . '/js/' . $plugin_slug . '.js', array('jquery'), '', true);

    $qib_settings_page = new qty_increment_buttons_settings();  

    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'qib_create_button_before' );        
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity', 'qib_create_button_after' );

    // js variable name => variable value       
    $data = array (
        'qib_button_size' => $qib_settings_page->qib_get_settings('qib_button_size'),               
    );

    wp_localize_script( $plugin_short_slug, 'phpVars', $data ); 

}

function qib_create_button_before() {           
    echo qib_create_button( true );
}

function qib_create_button_after() {
    echo qib_create_button( false );
}

function qib_create_button( $is_before ) {  
    $sign = ( 1 == $qib_settings_page->qib_get_settings('qib_minus_first') && $is_before === true ? '-' : '+' );
    return sprintf('<button type="button" class="%1$s" >%2$s</button>', $sign === '-' ? 'minus' : 'plus', $sign );  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/332656/30597

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this. In my other project I use this function in my settings class:

```
public function lal_get_settings( $index = false ) {

    $defaults = array ( 'lal_display_type' => 'icon', 'lal_add_fa' => false);
    $settings = get_option( 'lal_settingz', $defaults );

    if ( $index && isset( $settings[ $index ] ) ) {
        return $settings[ $index ];
    }

    return $settings;
}
```

Then outside the class in the main php file:

```
$args = array (
        'display_type' =>  $lal_settingz_page->lal_get_settings('lal_display_type'),
        'add_fa' =>  $lal_settingz_page->lal_get_settings('lal_add_fa')
);
```

Whenever I want to pass these settings as arguments, I use the following construction:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() use ( $args ) { login_account_logout( $args ); }, 1);
function login_account_logout( $args ) {
if ( $args['display_type'] === 'icon' && $args['add_fa'] == 1 )
    wp_enqueue_style('lal-CDN-font-awesome', '//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css');
}
```

I can pass these arguments further, to nested actions in the same way.